# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float' Python

Tags: python

I have this code which give me the error: `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'`

```
    currentPrice= client.get_klines(symbol=symbolOne, interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE)
    Ticker= client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbolOne)
    tickerPrice= Ticker['price']
    
    print(tickerPrice)

        output: 0.00000069
    
    plusOnePercentPrice= tickerPrice + (percentage(10, tickerPrice))
```

The output of tickerPrice have decimals and is not a string, I'm trying to get 1% of tickerPrice with this method:

```
    def percentage(percent, whole):
        return (percent * whole) / 100.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The output of tickerPrice have decimals and is not a string" The error message says otherwise. Note that ``print("0.00000069")`` produces the output ``0.00000069``. Have you verified the type of ``tickerPrice`` in any other way than inspecting how its value is printed? Did you ``print(type(tickerPrice))``, for example?

Comment: Take note that if you are working with finance/prices, ``float`` is inappropriate. Use ``decimal.Decimals``, ``fractions.Fraction`` or a third-part arbitrary precision type for correct results.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi When doing print(type(tickerPrice)) it does indeed print str! I thought it had to be in "" marks. Thanks!

Comment: where would i implement decimals.Decimals?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That means that the `percent` and `whole` variables are treated as a string. Changing them to the `float` type should work.

```
def percentage(percent, whole):
        return (float(percent) * float(whole)) / 100.0
```

The output you received `0.000000707e-08` Means `0.000000707 * 10^-8`

Comment: Then i get the error  ``` can only concatenate str (not "float") to str ```

Comment: use then `return str((float(percent) * float(whole)) / 100.0)`

Comment: That worked! But now I'm getting the number in this format: 0.000000707e-08

Comment: @normal_human Glad to hear. Can you upvote me and accept my answer? I will explain why it is showing like that in a minute.

Comment: @normal_human check edited answer from me.

Comment: is there a function i could write that automatically converts these kind of numbers into readable decimals?

Comment: @normal_human wdym by that. What would you like to input and what as an output?

Comment: well having a numbers in formats like these as input: 0.000049504.95e-06 and getting an output with a more readable number like 0.000049504000.
Or being able to choose that i only want 8 decimals

Comment: `0.000049504.95e-06` is equal to `0.000000000049504.95` not `0.000049504000`

Answer (score 0):

`Ticker['price']` probably contains the price as a string, convert it to float:

```
tickerPrice = float(Ticker['price'])
```

This causes `percent * whole` to repeat the price string 10 times instead of multiplication.

Answer (score -1):

Well firstly if you want to add 1% then replace 10 with 1 and
use float(tickerPrice) instead of tickerPrice in the last line